# PHP Mailer and Office 365 configuration

Tags: office365, phpmailer

My company have changed from local webserver email to office 365 and now the emails are not received.
I'm trying this configuration but not working

```php
  $mailer = new PHPMailer();
  $mailer - > IsSMTP();
  $mailer - > SMTPDebug = 3;
  $mailer - > Port = 587;
  $mailer - > Host = 'smtp.office365.com';
  $mailer - > SMTPAuth = true;
  $mailer - > Username = "xxxxxx";
  $mailer - > Password = "xxxxxx";
  $mailer - > SMTPOptions = array('ssl' => array('verify_peer' => false, 'verify_peer_name' => false, 'allow_self_signed' => true));
  $mailer - > FromName = 'Bart S. Locaweb';
  $mailer - > From = 'remetente@email.com.br';
  $mailer - > AddAddress('destinatario@email.com', 'Nome do destinatário');
  $mailer - > Subject = 'Teste enviado através do PHP Mailer SMTPLW';
  $mailer - > Body = 'Este é um teste realizado com o PHP Mailer SMTPLW';

  if (!$mailer - > Send()) {
    echo "Message was not sent";
    echo "Mailer Error: ".$mailer - > ErrorInfo;
    exit;
  }

  print "E-mail enviado!";
}
```

I have read several stuff related to this subject and the first thing to do was to check if i have connection with office 365 server...and i have

```
Testing smtp.gmail.com:587: successfull connected
Testing smtp.gmail.com:465: ERROR: 101 - Network is unreachable
Testing smtp.office365.com:587: successfull connected
```

So i don't get why i receive this notifocation

```
SMTP ERROR: Password command failed: 535 Incorrect authentication data
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 loge.dnsloge.com closing connection
Connection: closed
SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
Message was not sentMailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

and the user and pass are correct....any help?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Yes, of course, contact the provider, it seems they are blocking

Answer (score 0):

The steps was to contact the provider to allow office 365 emails

thanks